# UWP Как вытащить данные из FlipView о том какой элемент кликнут?

Tags: c#, uwp

Элементы `FlipView` строятся по шаблону привязанному к классу. Необходимо по клику вытащить определенные данные из класса по которому построен элемент. В `ListView` это делается, например, так:

```
private void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    user.user_Id = ((Class)e.ClickedItem).user_id.ToString();
}
```

Как это сделать в `FlipView`?

Comment: Посмотрите с помощью отладчика свойство `sender.DataContext`, возможно там уже лежит то что вам нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант - получать выбранный элемент из `FlipView` напрямую:

```
private void FlipView_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = (sender as FlipView).SelectedItem;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Все работает. На столько хорошо, что даже по нажатию навигационных кнопок обрабатывает событие. Можно как нибудь сделать, чтобы только по типу контента вызывалось событие?

Comment: @Denisok по типу какого контента? ([обновить вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/680020/edit))

Comment: по тапу контента*

Comment: Все, решил проблему обращением не к FlipView, к Grid в элементах FlipView